# Unexpected token, expected ")" in React component (if statement)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to create a variable and a for loop inside of a functional component to show the rating stars in a product but when I try to compile it, it keeps giving me the same error :

```
SyntaxError: Rating.js: Unexpected token, expected ")" 

for(let i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   if({value}>i && {value}<i+1) {
                          ^ 
     stars.push(
     <i
      key={i}
```

I don't know if you can't put a for loop inside of a functional component, if there's something extra I don't know that I shouldn't be doing or if I really have a syntax error.

The full code of the component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Rating = ({value, text, color}) => {

   let stars = [];

    for(let i=0; i<4; i++) 
    {
        if({value}>i && {value}<i+1) { //<-- 
            stars.push(
                <i 
                key={i}
                style={{color}}
                className={
                        'fas fa-star-half-alt'
                }
                />
            
            )}  else if({value}>i) {
                stars.push(
                <i 
                key={i}
                style={{color}}
                className={
                        'fas fa-star'
                }
                />

            )} else {
            stars.push(
                <i 
                key={i}
                style={{color}}
                className={
                        'far fa-star'
                }
                />
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='rating'>
            <span> 
                    {stars}
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Rating
```

Comment: remove {} around ``value``. also, remove it from ``color``.

Comment: `{value}` is an object literal or new block scope in JS scope. You likely want to remove the curly brackets. My guess is that it thinks `<i` is the start of some JSX, add in proper whitespace, i.e. `< i + `.

Comment: @SimaAmini The `style={{color}}` is correct syntax for passing an object with `color` as a property as a prop value.

Comment: `{value}` is used in JSX when you want to pass the variable as attribute: `<input value={value} />`. Outside JSX it's a shortcut for an object literal: `{ "value": value }`.

Comment: @DrewReese you're right!

Comment: @DrewReese and ChrisG Thank you!! It was just that haha 

Comment: Here's my version: https://codesandbox.io/s/rating-stars-94omg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

The root cause that you are using interpolation in a wrong way. You don't need to use `{}` outside of your JSX template, that is why JS blames `{value}` your `if` statement is JS code, you need to use `{}` when you want to embed some JS value into your JSX template e.g. `<span>{value}</span>`

```
import React from 'react'

const Rating = ({value, text, color}) => {

   let stars = [];

    for(let i=0; i<4; i++) 
    {
        if(value > i && value < i+1) {
            stars.push(
                <i 
                key={i}
                style={{color}}
                className={
                        'fas fa-star-half-alt'
                }
                />
            
            )}  else if( value > i) {
                stars.push(
                <i 
                key={i}
                style={{color}}
                className={
                        'fas fa-star'
                }
                />

            )} else {
            stars.push(
                <i 
                key={i}
                style={{color}}
                className={
                        'far fa-star'
                }
                />
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='rating'>
            <span> 
                    {stars}
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Rating
```